# Is it possible to react to Brightcove events on Apple devices?

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I was trying to build a video / image slider for mobile devices and I'm using Brightcove to display my videos.

Though due to limitations in the Brightcove versions I'm struggling to get my slider to work after a video has been played since I remove my overlay and Brightcove inserts an Iframe which disables pretty much all of my touch events (which are handled via hammer.js).

Let me show you my code:

Slider Markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class='slide'>
        //Brightcove Player get's inserted here. Images are displayed via background
    </div>
    <div class='slideprevious'>
    </div>
    <div class='slidefollowing'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Brightcove Initialisation:

```
var addVideo = function(){
    $('.slide').append('<div id="tsVideoPlayer"></div>');

    tsCreatePlayer('tsVideoPlayer', slides.eq(num).data('video-id'), 'XXXXXXXX');

    if(typeof bcPlayer === 'undefined'){
         $.when(
             //asynchronous loading of JS
             $.getScript( "http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences_all.js" ),
             $.getScript( "/xxx/xxx/brightcove_video.js" ),
             $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
                 $( deferred.resolve );
             })
          ).done(function(){
             addVideo();
          });
     } else {
          addVideo();
     }
```

Event Handling:

```
function getPlayerId(data) {
    for (var prop in data)
        return prop;
}
var player = bcPlayer.getExperience(getPlayerId(bcPlayer.experienceObjects)).modules.videoPlayer;

player.addEventListener(BCMediaEvent.PLAY, onPlayEventFired);
player.addEventListener(BCMediaEvent.STOP, onStopEventFired);

function onPlayEventFired() {
    alert("play");
}

 function onStopEventFired() {
    alert("stop");
 }
```

brightcove_video.js: http://pastebin.com/fTL5Uhqc

This actually works flawlessly on my Desktop in every browser. But as soon as I test it on Apple devices it doesn't work since the Flash Object isn't loaded anymore, but instead an iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Brightcove player API versions -- the legacy Flash-only player API and the Smart Player API. You're using the former which as you've guessed by now doesn't work with HTML players.

[This doc on the Brightcove support site](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/refactoring-your-flash-only-player-code-smart-player-code) details refactoring your code from the old to the new player API.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, but I found out that I'm not able to use the Smart Player API, since our advert company can't produce ads for that.

Comment: That sounds unusual. Normally Brightcove video ad partners work by running a plugin/translator in the player. Even if they use the Flash-only API in a swf plugin that wouldn't preclude you from also using the smart player API in js on the page.

Comment: The ads work, but for some reason they don't want us to implement it in the Smart Player API. I don't know if there is some tracking reason behind this, or if they aren't really sure how the Smart Player API works.